# Find list of all columns whose value fall between specific columns in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have Spark DF which consists of 20 columns from which I want to find which value of column falls between `High` and  `Low` column values.

```
Time,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,High,Low
09:16,930.9476296,927.4296671,924.1894385,923.2636589,921.6898335,920.578898,919.4679625,918.171871,915.95,913.728129,912.4320375,911.321102,910.2101665,908.6363411,907.7105615,904.4703329,900.9523704,919.95,917.65
```

I tried below command and it gave an error:

```
joineddata.withColumn('RR', map(lambda x: [x], ((F.col(x) >= (F.col('Low')) & (F.col(x) <= (F.col('High')) for x in joineddata.columns[1:18]))))).show()
```

**Error**:

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

**Desired Result**:

I want to have a new column which is a list of column names whose value falls between `High` and `Low` column.

```
Time,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,High,Low,RR
09:16,930.9476296,927.4296671,924.1894385,923.2636589,921.6898335,920.578898,919.4679625,918.171871,915.95,913.728129,912.4320375,911.321102,910.2101665,908.6363411,907.7105615,904.4703329,900.9523704,919.95,917.65,[2,1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just collect column names in an array using [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.when) and [`between`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.between) to check if a column satisfies the condition and then filter the resulted array to remove the null-values (columns that do not satisfy condition):

```
df = joineddata.withColumn('RR', array(*[when(col(c).between(col('Low'), col("High")), lit(c)) for c in df.columns[1:18]]))\
               .withColumn('RR', expr("filter(RR, x -> x is not null)"))

df.select("Time", "RR").show()

#+-----+------+
#| Time|    RR|
#+-----+------+
#|09:16|[2, 1]|
#+-----+------+
```

Note that in the second step the [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#filter) function is used which is only available from Spark 2.4+. For older versions, you can use UDF.

Comment: df = joineddata.withColumn('RR', array(*[F.when(F.col(c).between(F.col('Low'), F.col("High")), F.lit(c)) for c in joineddata.columns[1:18]])).withColumn('RR', expr("filter(RR, x -> x is not null)"))


Getting below error:

TypeError: array() takes at most 2 arguments (17 given)

Comment: You're probably using Python array... Try `F.array` instead

Comment: @blackbishop is the filter function that you mentioned only available in databricks runtime? i cant seem to find on new open source docs

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi No, it's in Spark starting from version 2.4.0, see the link.